# How to understand type in the function body instead of in the function parameter list

Tags: scala, playframework

In file of Action.scala in play framework, there is a following function:

```
  final def apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])
         (block: R[A] => Result): Action[A] 
         = async(bodyParser) { req: R[A] =>
    Future.successful(block(req))
  }
```

there is a section as below:

```
  { req: R[A] =>
        Future.successful(block(req))
      }
```

If in a function parameter list: that means req is a type of

```
   R[A] =>Future.successful(block(req))
```

But it used req in block(req), so looks like recursive. And now it's not in parameter list but in a body, how to understand it?

Comment: No, req is of type R[A],  req: R[A] =>Future.successful(block(req)) is a function that takes a object of type R[A] and returns Future.successful(block(req))

Comment: @Siphor You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, req is of type R[A].
req: R[A] =>Future.successful(block(req)) is a function that takes a object of type R[A] and returns Future.successful(block(req))

Example:

```
def fun(param:Int=>String)=param(9)
```

declares a function that takes a function as a parameter

```
def fun2 = fun({i:Int=>i.toString})
```

gives fun a implemented function

Comment: If we have "def fun(param:Int=>String)", it says param is a function takes an Int and produces a String. But req: R[A] =>Future.successful(block(req))  is totally different, could you please fake an easy example function to help understand it?